# POSIX path in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to run a bash script as sudo from AppleScript and I want to fill in the user name and password, I have googled out this solution:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  do shell script ("sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/run_mysql_sudo '" & POSIX path of input & "'") user name "username" password "pass" with administrator privileges
end run
```

but I get an error saying: `Can’t make POSIX path into type Unicode text.`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely input is a list of items. Even if it only has one item in it, it's still a list so you have to get the first item of the list to use it. Your error is because you can't get the posix path of a list.

Second, in applescript we use "with administrator privileges" instead of sudo. We don't use both. Last applescript has "quoted form of" to properly quote things.

As such, give this a try...

```
set firstItemOfInput to item 1 of input
do shell script ("/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/run_mysql_sudo " & quoted form of POSIX path of firstItemOfInput) user name "username" password "pass" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Although I knew about the list thing, in my tests I used the code in an Automator  Run Applescript and used the `  ls` command. The input came from a   "Get Selected Finder Items" . I had 1 folder selected. Just quoting worked and I did not need to specify item. So thats all I put in my answer. But you are right it is best practice to specify item when possibly coming from a list. And I completely forgot about the sudo. So I will remove mine and +1 yours.

Comment: I have tried exactly what you are suggesting but now it complains "The variable firstItemOfInput is not defined."